# Make responsive Checkbox in HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need to make the checkbox responsive (in .HTML file), i.e on select of checkbox the url of the page should get modified and page should get refreshed. Following is my code, right now the checkboxes are modifying the url but as soon as it is refreshed the loose their state also I need to modify url on uncheck. Please HELP.

```
var $checkes = $('input:checkbox[name="ch"]').change(function () {
    var vals = $checkes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    var newurl = document.location.href;
    for (k in vals) {
        newurl = newurl + "+" + vals[k];
    }
    document.location.href = newurl;
    var i = newurl.lastIndexOf('/');
    var checkedOnes = newurl.substr(i + 1).split('+');

    var len = checkedOnes.length;
    for (var i = 2; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementById(checkedOnes[i]).checked = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: My url is of this format: "http://www.abcd.com/en/note+note1+imp_1+imp_2+imp_3"

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/), 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 0):

First off, it doesn't look like you're setting any query string values (the stuff after a question mark at the end of a URL)

As HTTP is stateless, it makes sense that your checkboxes don't retain their state after page reload.

The way around this, if you're using purely front end technologies, is to set the checkboxes through JavaScript on page load

The code you've got, `var i` and onwards, shouldn't be in the event handler. That appears to be the code you're using to set the checkboxes to checked or not so it being there will only fire when a checkbox is changed. However, the page reloads before that code can ever execute

I hope that clears things up somewhat

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense. And, it worked. But, I have one more issue now, I need to trim my url and want only the first part of it.
Eg my url is "abcd.com/en/note+note1+imp_1+imp_2+imp_3"
Mow, I need only  "abcd.com/en/note+note1".
How to do it!!

Comment: First off, change the format to abcd.com/en?... In fact, the bit after the question mark should follow the format <id>=<value> and separate multiple id-value pairs with an &. I don't remember the JS off the top of my head (on my phone at the moment) but something like `document.location` should get you what you want, provided you follow the format I explained

Comment: As an aside, if you're not already using it, check out Chrome's dev tools. They're amazingly useful for messing with JS snippets